# Расширение файлов .url в Windows

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система

Если изменить расширение любого файла на .url, то расширение файла пропадёт и изменить его уже не получится в Windows. Как можно отобразить расширение файлов .url

Comment: "показать расширения" показывает расширения всех файлов, кроме .url

Comment: @Alexei, ещё кроме lnk. Ну и pif я не проверял.

Answer (score 3):

Из консоли (в папке с файлом):

```
ren some-file.url some-file.zip
```

Ну и не забывать про кавычки, если там пробелы есть. Впрочем, консоль сама их поставит, если пользоваться автодополнением <kbd>tab</kbd>.